# The engine start just fine, but when I try to get on the road the engine shuts off when I accelerate

Tags: starting, stall, acceleration

On a Chinese Scooter 50cc Bash, my engine start fine, but when I try to get on the road the engine shuts off when I accelerate. On the very bottom of the carburetor there there a line and I don't know where it connects Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you provide a picture of the line?

Comment: The line from the bottom of the float bowl is probably a drain tube, so you can easily catch the gasoline when you drain the carburetors for storage. It's not supposed to be connected to anything, and is probably unrelated to your issue. It shouldn't have any gasoline coming out of it. If gasoline is coming from the tube, you need to close the drain screw.